# ML Increment Integer Ref

Tags: integer, increment, sml, ml, ref

I have a list of int ref's my function takes. How could I increment the int at the head of the list, then recurse on the tail? Can ML do multiple lines per function (it seems like I can only do one statement (like if..else..) and write other clauses/code under that without getting an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would really help if you provided more information, but I can at least explain how the general idea works.

ML uses the `;` character to build a single expression out of two. Given two expressions, `e1` and `e2`, you can create the expression `(e1 ; e2)` (Parentheses not optional -- it won't work without them), which will evaluate everything in `e1` and then `e2`, and has the same value as `e2`, if `e2` has a value.

This is a bit abstract, so here are a few examples:

```
val a_ref = ref 0;
fun f x = (x := !x + 1; !x);
f a_ref;
```

This will set the value in `a_ref` to 1, and then return that value.

Keeping the same ref, but defining a new function:

```
fun g x = (x := !x + 1; x := (if !x == 2 then 0 else 1); 42);
g a_ref;
```

This will first increment the value in `a_ref` (to 2), then check that it equals 2, and so set it to zero, and then return 42.

Hopefully these sort of help your understanding of how `;` works.

Now, going on to what you actually seem to want:

Given a list `l`, if you want to do something to every element of the list, you could try using `app`. For example:

```
app (fn x => x := !x + 1) l;
```

will increment each of the refs in the list.

Alternately, if you want to use recursion,

```
fun f [] = []
  | f (x::xs) = (x := !x + 1; x::(f xs))
```

This will increment each of the refs and then return the list. If you instead don't want to return the list,

```
fun f [] = ()
  | f (x::xs) = (x := !x + 1; f xs);
```

is another option, that will give `unit` instead.

If you want to do something more complicated than just incrementing every element, the arguments to f can be changed as suitable.

Comment: "Parentheses not optional -- it won't work without them" That's not entirely true. If the body of a `let` is an `;` expression, the parentheses are optional.